# Median calculation in spark 1.6 Error: expected but identifier DIV found

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to calculate median on latitude column based on  group (destinationid and LocationID) column
Scala Spark 1.6

Data in JSON looks like:

```
DESTINATION_ID,LOCATION_ID,LATITUDE
[ENSG00000257017,EAST_0000182,0.07092000000000001]
[ENSG00000257017,WEST_0001397,0.07092000000000001]
[ENSG00000181965,EAST_1001951,0.07056000000000001]
[ENSG00000146648,EAST_0000616,0.07092000000000001]
[ENSG00000111537,WEST_0001845,0.07092000000000001]
[ENSG00000103222,EAST_0000565,0.07056000000000001]
[ENSG00000118137,EAST_0000508,0.07092000000000001]
[ENSG00000112715,EAST_0000616,0.07092000000000001]
[ENSG00000108984,EAST_0000574,0.07056000000000001]
[ENSG00000159640,NORTH_797,0.07092000000000001]
[ENSG00000113522,NORTH_790,0.07056000000000001]
[ENSG00000133895,NORTH_562,0.07056000000000001]
```

Code

```
 var ds = sqlContext.sql("""
   SELECT DESTINATION_ID,LOCATION_ID, avg(LATITUDE) as median
FROM ( SELECT DESTINATION_ID,LOCATION_ID, LATITUDE, rN, (CASE WHEN cN % 2 = 0 then (cN DIV 2) ELSE (cN DIV 2) + 1 end) as m1, (cN DIV 2) + 1 as m2
        FROM (
            SELECT DESTINATION_ID,LOCATION_ID, LATITUDE, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY DESTINATION_ID,LOCATION_ID ORDER BY LATITUDE ) as rN, 
        count(LATITUDE) OVER (PARTITION BY DESTINATION_ID,LOCATION_ID ) as cN
            FROM people
         ) s
    ) r
WHERE rN BETWEEN m1 and m2
GROUP BY DESTINATION_ID,LOCATION_ID
""")
```

Error:

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [3.98] failure: ``)'' 
expected but identifier DIV found**
```

Please help me if i am missing something.
Or
Techie please guide me Is there any better way to calculate median in spark

Thanks

Comment: Why are yiu using `DIV` and not `/`?

Comment: @SomeshwarKale: Yes i was using / earlier but got error like :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [5.86] failure: ``)'' expected but `(' found.

Comment: Techie Please help me if there is any other better way to calculate median in spark scala 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to execute the above query with the test input you provided, as below-

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |DESTINATION_ID,LOCATION_ID,LATITUDE
        |ENSG00000257017,EAST_0000182,0.07092000000000001
        |ENSG00000257017,WEST_0001397,0.07092000000000001
        |ENSG00000181965,EAST_1001951,0.07056000000000001
        |ENSG00000146648,EAST_0000616,0.07092000000000001
        |ENSG00000111537,WEST_0001845,0.07092000000000001
        |ENSG00000103222,EAST_0000565,0.07056000000000001
        |ENSG00000118137,EAST_0000508,0.07092000000000001
        |ENSG00000112715,EAST_0000616,0.07092000000000001
        |ENSG00000108984,EAST_0000574,0.07056000000000001
        |ENSG00000159640,NORTH_797,0.07092000000000001
        |ENSG00000113522,NORTH_790,0.07056000000000001
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\,").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS)
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---------------+------------+-------------------+
      * |DESTINATION_ID |LOCATION_ID |LATITUDE           |
      * +---------------+------------+-------------------+
      * |ENSG00000257017|EAST_0000182|0.07092000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000257017|WEST_0001397|0.07092000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000181965|EAST_1001951|0.07056000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000146648|EAST_0000616|0.07092000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000111537|WEST_0001845|0.07092000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000103222|EAST_0000565|0.07056000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000118137|EAST_0000508|0.07092000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000112715|EAST_0000616|0.07092000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000108984|EAST_0000574|0.07056000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000159640|NORTH_797   |0.07092000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000113522|NORTH_790   |0.07056000000000001|
      * +---------------+------------+-------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- DESTINATION_ID: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- LOCATION_ID: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- LATITUDE: double (nullable = true)
      */
```

```scala
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
    spark.sql(
      """
        |SELECT
        |  DESTINATION_ID,
        |  LOCATION_ID,
        |  avg(LATITUDE) as median
        |FROM
        |  (
        |    SELECT
        |      DESTINATION_ID,
        |      LOCATION_ID,
        |      LATITUDE,
        |      rN,
        |      (
        |        CASE WHEN cN % 2 = 0 then (cN / 2) ELSE (cN / 2) + 1 end
        |      ) as m1,
        |      (cN / 2) + 1 as m2
        |    FROM
        |      (
        |        SELECT
        |          DESTINATION_ID,
        |          LOCATION_ID,
        |          LATITUDE,
        |          row_number() OVER (
        |            PARTITION BY DESTINATION_ID,
        |            LOCATION_ID
        |            ORDER BY
        |              LATITUDE
        |          ) as rN,
        |          count(LATITUDE) OVER (PARTITION BY DESTINATION_ID, LOCATION_ID) as cN
        |        FROM
        |          people
        |      ) s
        |  ) r
        |WHERE
        |  rN BETWEEN m1
        |  and m2
        |GROUP BY
        |  DESTINATION_ID,
        |  LOCATION_ID
      """.stripMargin)
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +--------------+-----------+------+
      * |DESTINATION_ID|LOCATION_ID|median|
      * +--------------+-----------+------+
      * +--------------+-----------+------+
      */
```

> You need to check your query or input, its not providing any output

check IF THE BELOW QUERY HELPS -

```scala
spark.sql(
      """
        |SELECT *
        |FROM people k NATURAL JOIN
        |(SELECT
        |  DESTINATION_ID,
        |  LOCATION_ID,
        |  avg(LATITUDE) as median
        |FROM
        |  (
        |    SELECT
        |      DESTINATION_ID,
        |      LOCATION_ID,
        |      LATITUDE,
        |      rN,
        |      (
        |        CASE WHEN cN % 2 = 0 then (cN / 2) ELSE (cN / 2) - 1 end
        |      ) as m1,
        |      (cN / 2) + 1 as m2
        |    FROM
        |      (
        |        SELECT
        |          DESTINATION_ID,
        |          LOCATION_ID,
        |          LATITUDE,
        |          row_number() OVER (
        |            PARTITION BY DESTINATION_ID,
        |            LOCATION_ID
        |            ORDER BY
        |              LATITUDE
        |          ) as rN,
        |          count(LATITUDE) OVER (PARTITION BY DESTINATION_ID, LOCATION_ID) as cN
        |        FROM
        |          people
        |      ) s
        |  ) r
        |WHERE
        |  rN BETWEEN m1
        |  and m2
        |GROUP BY
        |  DESTINATION_ID,
        |  LOCATION_ID
        |  ) t
      """.stripMargin)
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
      * |DESTINATION_ID |LOCATION_ID |LATITUDE           |median             |
      * +---------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
      * |ENSG00000111537|WEST_0001845|0.07092000000000001|0.07092000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000257017|WEST_0001397|0.07092000000000001|0.07092000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000103222|EAST_0000565|0.07056000000000001|0.07056000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000108984|EAST_0000574|0.07056000000000001|0.07056000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000112715|EAST_0000616|0.07092000000000001|0.07092000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000113522|NORTH_790   |0.07056000000000001|0.07056000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000118137|EAST_0000508|0.07092000000000001|0.07092000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000146648|EAST_0000616|0.07092000000000001|0.07092000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000159640|NORTH_797   |0.07092000000000001|0.07092000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000181965|EAST_1001951|0.07056000000000001|0.07056000000000001|
      * |ENSG00000257017|EAST_0000182|0.07092000000000001|0.07092000000000001|
      * +---------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
      */
```

Comment: Thank You very much Someshwar, yes the present query is giving error, i tried to fix changing DIV with / , but error still exists. is there any other way i can calculate median . Please help me.

Comment: is there any better way to calculate median in spark. Please help me.

Comment: Hello Sir...... the above solution is throwing error as : Cannot resolve destination_id. given input column :[s.rN,s.id,s.cN,s.id,s.LATITUDE. Please help me Sir